# Modifying brushless alternator for external regulator

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, alternator

I'd like to modify a Delco Remy 38si or 40si brushless alternator for use with an external voltage regulator.  For a brushed alternator, I'd just need to pull the field out external to the case.  My expectation is that the same would work for any brushless alternator.

Are there issues here I'm not seeing?

Can someone speak directly to these specific alternators and the possibility for removing the voltage regulator (obviously possible) and pulling the field out to an external terminal?

Comment: so does a brushless alternator have a field you can vary? A link to something technical on one would be good.

Comment: Many brushless alternators are already controlled externally by the engine ecu to reduce energy demand during acceleration or full power demand.

Comment: Some of the Delco Remy brushless alternators seem to have a field configuration that is similar to the rotating field models. They have a similar coil inside a claw-pole rotor, but the coil is stationary and the rotor has a bearing on only one  end. The field energizes the rotor through secondary air-gap. It is possible that the 38i and 40i have a design using a rotating rectifier. If that is the case, the stationary part of the field circuit may include an inverter. That would make using a different kind of regulator a different ballgame.

Comment: Now cross posted here: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/76651/10976

Comment: The rectifier on the 40si seems to be a stationary component according to http://www.delcoremy.com/find-a-part/service-parts/alternator/40si - the 38si shares a similar design.  Neil_UK: there is a field that can be varied.  This is the best doc I've found: http://www.delcoremy.com/documents/alternator-instruction-sheets/replacement-components-instructions-33si,-34si,-35.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a brushless alternator would be two-in-one, comprising a main one and an exciter, axially side-by-side.

In the main alternator, the stator would be the armature and the rotor the field, whereas in the exciter, the stator would be the field and the rotor the armature.  This configuration would enable the exciter armature to feed the main field through a bridge rectifier, without the need for slip rings.

The exciter field winding would be fed by the main armature through a bridge rectifier and regulator.

The main rectifier block and regulator block would be separate sub-assemblies.
Should the regulator block have bolt terminals, it could be removed and its input and output cables brought out, to connect an external regulator.

Comment: Thank you, Peter.